# Swift: Custom class array in table view - editing the values: accessory segue or other?

Tags: uitableview, swift, segue, accessoryview

I have a custom class Medication with variables name and directions.  I have this in an array presenting itself in a tableview showing Medication.name and Medication.directions.

I'd like the user to be able to click either on the row or on the accessory button (Detail?) to edit the value in the selected row.

My ideal situation would be a menu that dropped down from the bottom of the selected row with editable fields that would update the row in the array and reload the tableview.

Is there a way to accomplish this or something similar? I was playing around with hidden view fields and having them show when the row is selected, but I'm not sure if I can anchor one to the bottom of the selected row?  Or I could build a custom cell that has the editable fields in each cell, hidden, with a fixed height to the cell that changes upon clicking it to show the extra fields.

Likewise, if the best option is to use the accessory view, is Detail the most appropriate one?  I can't seem to right click and drag a segue for this.  Or would I just use this below?

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

If I segue this to another view controller, I'll need to use delegates obviously to change the array from the tableview so I'm hoping to find a simpler solution.

Thanks! Appreciate any tips for this newbie

Here's where I'm stuck with the segue:

```
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MedDetailViewController
        vc.delegate = self
        let MedRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let passMed = myMedsList[MedRow]  //this row doesn't work
        vc.detailMed = passMed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A segue is not only the simplest way to accomplish this, you can also take advantage of an unwind segue to automatically return your edited values.

No delegation needed.  No custom code to add hidden views to your cell.

If you only have one segue, add it to the row, not the accessory.  Users tend to expect that tapping on the row does something.  If it didn't do anything, most users wouldn't then try tapping on the accessory.

*Tapping on the accessory is meant as a secondary action that does something different from tapping on the row.*

I would setup the `show` segue right in Storyboard.  Less code to write, less code to maintain.  Let Storyboard do the work for you.

**Update:**

Here's Apple's tech note about [Using Unwind Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html), along with their Swift example of how the destination (presenting) view controller accesses data from the source (presented) view controller.

```
@IBAction func unwindToMainMenu(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as! MedDetailViewController
    // Update the medsList array with the new detailMed
    let medRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row
    medsList[medRow] = sourceViewController.detailMed
}
```

**Update 2:**

You want to update the detail view controller's detailMed property before you unwind the segue, using the prepareForSegue: method.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToMedications"
    {
        // Update the detailMed if the user has edited it
        self.detailMed = ... // the edited medication you're returning
    }
}
```

**Update 3:**

The back button (or swiping back) simply pops the pushed view controller off the stack, but there's no segue that's being called.  You need to explicitly hook up a segue from a Done button that will unwind for you **and update the meds list**.

The reason why you explicitly unwind is to distinguish between whether the user wants to commit or cancel any change.  (Did they make a change, but they want to ignore it, so they pressed Back?)

You have two options, which both will work, and it's up to you how you want to present the editable details.  (I prefer push to show details, and modal for editing forms, but either way works).

1. Push the detail view controller.  Have a Done button.  The user can use the Back button to cancel, or the Done button to accept any changed med details.
2. Present a modal view controller with Cancel and Done buttons.  Again, the user can cancel (return without changes), or tap Done to (return and) accept changes.

For either presentation, you hook up an unwind segue to the Done button.  What this will do is call the Meds list view controller unwind action.  In that unwind code, you get the med details and update the meds list, as we previously discussed.

**A mention about Core Data:**

There's an alternative approach which isn't simpler to learn than segues, but it's a great fit.  (Something to keep in mind, if not for this app, then for the next one.)

Core Data and `NSFetchedResultsController`.  You save the edited medication, and `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` updates the list of medications for you.

Some might say it's overkill, but since I started using NSFetchedResultsController, I wish I had learned it sooner.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll try that - very helpful tips.  The segue will let me show details on the selected cell, but if I want the user to be able to edit it and have those edits pass back to the original table, I would still need a delegate correct?

Comment: Not necessarily.  A delegate is one way to pass information back, but an unwind segue can be used instead of a delegate.  Unwind segues are a bit simpler and tend to require less code than delegation.  The destination view controller accesses the edited properties of the source (detail) view controller.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't get the class to pass through my segue.  I'm having trouble with the indexpath.  My code is:                                                             `let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MedDetailViewController`
            `vc.delegate = self`
            `let MedRow = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!`
            `let passMed = myMedsList[MedRow]  //this row isn't working`
           `vc.detailMed = passMed`       How do I fix that row so I can pass the complete Medication class reference to the appropriate row in my MyMedsList array?

Comment: I updated the original question so that comment is easier to read

Comment: Before you unwind, update your detail view controller's detailMed with the new (edited) `Medication`.  In the unwind, you access vc.detailMed, and update your MedsList.  I've updated the answer with more detail which should help.

Comment: Thank you so much - this was very helpful!  Last question for you - for an unwind, do I need to add it to the storyboard?  When I segue from my tableview into the next view controller (my detail page), there is already a "back" button built in.  Likewise, you can swipe back to go back to the tableview.  I assume this is already a built in unwind segue essentially?  So I add the code, it will just add those actions to the already built in unwind?  Thanks!

Comment: There's no built-in unwind segue.  I've updated the answer to explain the distinction between popping back, and unwinding, and why/how you have to hook up an unwind segue in Storyboard.  You're welcome, happy to help! :) Don't forget to accept the answer, so your question is marked as answered.